# How do I make PySpark SQL API return a timezone aware datetime object?

Tags: pyspark

I have the following unit test where I create a time zone aware `datetime` object and return it:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, TimestampType


def test_timezones() -> None:
    session = SparkSession.builder.master("local[4]").getOrCreate()

    df = session.createDataFrame(
        [(datetime(2022, 10, 1, 10, 53, tzinfo=timezone.utc),)],
        StructType(
            [
                StructField("my_field", TimestampType(), nullable=False),
            ]
        ),
    )

    assert df.take(1)[0].my_field == datetime(2022, 10, 1, 10, 53, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
```

Unfortunately it fails with:

```
Expected :datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 1, 10, 53, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
Actual   :datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 1, 11, 53)
```

Why am I not getting back the `datetime` I am expecting?

I am using pyspark 3.3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark is depending on your machine's local time zone (by default).

An option is to set the default timezone in python once without the need to pass the timezone each time in Spark and python

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, TimestampType

# Set default python timezone
import os, time
os.environ['TZ'] = 'UTC'
time.tzset()

df = spark.createDataFrame(
        [(datetime(2022, 10, 1, 10, 53),)],
        StructType(
            [
                StructField("my_field", TimestampType(), nullable=False),
            ]
        ),
    )

assert df.take(1)[0].my_field == datetime(2022, 10, 1, 10, 53)
```

---

Another option is to set `spark.sql.session.timeZone` setting (this is in case you don't want to collect the results again in python)

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, TimestampType

spark.conf.set('spark.sql.session.timeZone', 'UTC')
df = spark.createDataFrame(
        [(datetime(2022, 10, 1, 10, 53, tzinfo=timezone.utc),)],
        StructType(
            [
                StructField("my_field", TimestampType(), nullable=False),
            ]
        ),
    )

df.show()
```

```sql
+-------------------+
|           my_field|
+-------------------+
|2022-10-01 10:53:00|
+-------------------+
```

Comment: The unit test fails in the same way.

Comment: Since you are collecting in python then you need to set the default timezone in python, I have edited the answer to allow another option of setting only the python timezone without the Spark setting and removing the timezone from the created datetimes

Comment: Thanks. The `time.tzset()` option makes my unit test pass. Do you know the reasoning behind why Spark chooses to mess around with the input `datetime` timezone? I hoped it would just return it as output just like it went in instead of having to set something globally in the Python and/or Spark runtimes.

Comment: I don't know tbh, but I guess because the `datetime` type in the Spark Dataframe doesn't have a timezone component, so even when you set a timezone when you create a datetime before passing it to `createDataFrame`, Spark ignores that bit and only keep the date/time based on the local timezone

Comment: Ok thanks. I did not know that. I assumed `TimestampType` contained a timezone as just below it there is [another class](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/types.html#TimestampType) called `TimestampNTZType` which is documented as not containing a timezone.